# How do I update street information for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

As the result of the end of some works, a street has changed its direction of travel.

Is there any way I can notify Google of the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bottom right corner of the map, you'll see a tiny link:  [image: report a problem].  This will bring up the *Report A Problem* dialog.

[image: dialog]

More information can be found [here](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=162873&hl=en) (it's the Learn More link in the dialog).

**EDIT:** Here is a page with a bit more information with other links and ways to edit information:  [Google Maps:  Fix a problem](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98014)

If this still doesn't work, the map provider is always listed at the bottom of the map.  Chances are good that they will have their own way for submitting corrections.  You'd need to identify the provider and then do a search.

Comment: Go figure, that tool isn't available in that area. (I'm still accepting your answer as I didn't specify where the problem was and since I don't really care too much about it -- if I did I would be working on OpenStreetMap.)

Comment: Awesome, that area is covered by TeleAtlas, which has its own [Report a problem](http://mapinsight.teleatlas.com/) system as linked by the "Fix a problem" link you added.